# How to parse JSON in Java and put values into Collection

Tags: java, json, parsing, collections

Is there a way in Java in which i can read from json and directly put it`s values in a Collection. In my case I have three different type. Can i make it :

```
Collection<Type> types;
```

JSON :

```
{
"type1":[
      {
        "version": "1.11",
        "releaseDate": "2015-03-26",
        "downloadUrl": "****"
      },
      {
        "version": "1.12",
        "releaseDate": "2015-04-08",
        "downloadUrl": "****"
      }],
"type2":[
      {
        "version": "2.20",
        "releaseDate": "2015-03-26",
        "downloadUrl": "****"
      },
      {
        "version": "2.21",
        "releaseDate": "2015-04-08",
        "downloadUrl": "****"
      }],
"type3":[
      {
        "version": "2.56",
        "releaseDate": "2015-03-26",
        "downloadUrl": "****"
      },
      {
        "version": "2.57",
        "releaseDate": "2015-04-08",
        "downloadUrl": "****"
      }]
}
```

Comment: how is ur Type class?

Comment: There are many Java APIs for JSON. One of them is here: http://www.json.org/java/.

Comment: maybe this should be a class that represent the 3 types i have, a class which have String version, realeaseDate and downloadUrl, but I don`t know how to do this

Comment: @alle3x you need to define a class called Type. then its just a simple method that takes a json as parameter and return you an Object Type.

Comment: Please do not upvote duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). I'm giving you basic idea change your as per your requirements like datatype, conventions, etc...

```
public class YourType{
 private String version;
 private String releaseDate;
 private String downloadUrl;
 // getter-setter
}
```

And

```
/* Code to convert JSON to Collection */
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

Type objType = new TypeToken<List<YourType>>(){}.getType();
List<YourType> list = objGson.fromJson(yourJSONObject.getJSONArray("type1").toString(), objType);
```

Comment: how should jsonObjectProduct variable look like ?

Comment: you could try this: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/. I copy pasted your code in to that page. It generated the code. You might want to take a look at it.

Comment: @alle3x Its mistake. It'll be your JSON Object

Comment: Down voter can you tell me why?